# Trailing slash and routes

Tags: traefik

I recently started experimenting with `traefik` and I'm swiching over from `nginx`.

I'm a bit confused by how the paths in `Path`, `PathStrip`, `PathPrefix` and `PathPrefixStrip` work regarding trailing slashes.

In `nginx` for proxied requests this is the documentation:

> If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash
>   character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass,
>   fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, scgi_pass, or memcached_pass, then the
>   special processing is performed. In response to a request with URI
>   equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent
>   redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with
>   the slash appended. If this is not desired, an exact match of the URI
>   and location could be defined like this:
>
> ```
> location /user/ {
>     proxy_pass http://user.example.com;
> }
>
> location = /user {
>     proxy_pass http://login.example.com;
> }
> ```

How would it be possible to replicate this behaviour?

Essentially I’d like `traefik` to append the trailing slash when not present, so that `PathPrefixStrip:/mylocation/` will also match `/mylocation` and issue a `301` for `/location/`.

In addition I'm a bit confused by the difference between `Path` and `PathPrefix` when used as `Modifiers`, is there some documentation that explains the difference in their respective behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: have you figured out the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, still helpful for novice traefik users.

This question was probably related with traefik 1.x, here the [official matchers documentation for 1.7](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/basics/#matchers)

It stands:

> Path: /products/, /articles/{category}/{id:[0-9]+}     Match exact request path. It accepts a sequence of literal and regular expression paths.
>
> ...
>
> PathPrefix: /products/, /articles/{category}/{id:[0-9]+}   Match request prefix path. It accepts a sequence of literal and regular expression prefix paths.

Also their are very clear about path [Path Matcher Usage Guidelines](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/basics/#path-matcher-usage-guidelines)

But this is old and deprecated in favor of the current version. So check the [latest documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/)

The traefik is very different on 2.x version. [You can check the migration guide here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/migration/v1-to-v2/)

Now you need to setup:

- entrypoints
- routers
- middlewares
- services

In your router, the `rule` property is where your set the `Path` or `PathPrefix` matcher. [The rule reference are here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#rule)

> Path(`/path`, `/articles/{cat:[a-z]+}/{id:[0-9]+}`, ...)   Match exact request path. It accepts a sequence of literal and regular expression paths.
>
> PathPrefix(`/products/`, `/articles/{cat:[a-z]+}/{id:[0-9]+}`)     Match request prefix path. It accepts a sequence of literal and regular expression prefix paths.